# BufferedImage swap red and blue channel

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, colors, bufferedimage

My goal is to swap the red and blue channels of a java `BufferedImage`.

Is there any way to achieve this other than inefficiently iterating over each pixel value und swapping the channels? I was thinking of some bitwise magic or some integrated function I don't know of.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution, that's really fast, as it doesn't really change the data, only the way the data is displayed.

The trick is that the channel order (byte order) is controlled by the `SampleModel`. And you can change the sample model without actually changing the data, to make the same data display differently.

If you already have a `BufferedImage`, the easiest way to create a sample model with swapped channels, is creating a new child `Raster`, using the `Raster.createWritableChild(...)` method, and specifying the channel (or "band") order in the last parameter.

```
bgr.getRaster().createWritableChild(0, 0, bgr.getWidth(), bgr.getHeight(), 0, 0, 
                                    new int[]{2, 1, 0}); // default order is 0, 1, 2
```

In the example below, the image data is the same (if in doubt, try moving the painting part, after cloning the image, and see that the result is the same). Only the channels are swapped:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Original
    final BufferedImage bgr = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    // Paint something
    Graphics2D graphics = bgr.createGraphics();
    try {
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, bgr.getWidth(), bgr.getHeight());
        graphics.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, bgr.getWidth(), bgr.getHeight() / 3);
        graphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, bgr.getWidth() / 3, bgr.getHeight());
    }
    finally {
        graphics.dispose();
    }

    // Clone, and swap BGR -> RGB
    ColorModel colorModel = bgr.getColorModel();
    WritableRaster swapped = bgr.getRaster().createWritableChild(0, 0, bgr.getWidth(), bgr.getHeight(), 0, 0, 
                                                                 new int[]{2, 1, 0}); // default order is 0, 1, 2
    final BufferedImage rgb = new BufferedImage(colorModel, swapped, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

    System.err.println("bgr: " + bgr); // TYPE_3BYTE_BGR (5)
    System.err.println("rgb: " + rgb); // TYPE_CUSTOM (0)

    // Display it all
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bgr)), BorderLayout.WEST);
            frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(rgb)));

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

---

PS: I know from the comments the OP don't need this, but if you really need to swap the channels of the pixel data for some reason (ie. needed by native library or so), the fastest would probably  be to get the data, loop over and swap the red and blue (1st and 3rd) components:

```
byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) bgr.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
    // Swap 1st and 3rd component
    byte b = data[i];
    data[i] = data[i + 2];
    data[i + 2] = b;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you create an new instance of `BufferedImage` with the same `WritableRaster raster` and the same properties, but with a ColorModel with the colors swaped:

e.g:

```
ColorModel swappedColorModel = new DirectColorModel(24,
                                              0x000000ff,   // Red -> Blue
                                              0x0000ff00,   // Green
                                              0x00ff0000,   // Blue -> Red
                                              0x0           // Alpha
                                              );
BufferedImage swapedColorImage = new BufferedImage (swappedColorModel,
                                                    originalImage.getRaster(),
                                                    swappedColorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(),
                                                    properties);
```

I didn't tried this code

Comment: If you didn’t write the vide, can you link to source of the solution?

Comment: This didn’t work for me. It crashes with the exception that I cannot use the color model with my image. The image is in 3BYTE_BGR format. Maybe there’s some issue with the non-existent alpha channel?

Comment: @DavidBauer I think the idea is sound (and fast!), however, for a `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` you need a `ComponentColorModel`, not a `DirectColorModel` (which work with `TYPE_INT_*` `BufferedImages`). However, this will not swap the channels of the data, only the way it is displayed. Your question is ambiguous with regards to whether this is okay or not.

Comment: It’s okay if the end result is the same. I just want to swap red and blue intensities in the image. How that is achieved doesn’t matter too much. Gonna try ComponentColorModel asap

Comment: ComponentColorModel did the trick. I also had to change the raster that was used in the BufferedImage. This post helped me out a lot too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639986/how-do-colormodels-and-writablerasters-work-in-java-bufferedimages

Comment: @haraldK could you post your answer here, so i can vote it